# Entity with custom fields database performance design

Tags: performance, postgresql, database-design, entity-relationship, relationships

I need to build an application where there are generic entities (let's say articles, pages, *nodes*) where the user can add custom fields.

I've seen the approach that the most popular php CMS (wp, drupal) use to get this goal; They all have the *base* table with the minimum fields (e.g. title and body), and then delegates all the other fields to other tables, for example:

```
table node
id | title | body

table field_foo
node_id | field_type | field_value

table field_bar
node_id | field_type | field_value
// and so on
```

This, in a full mvc environment is pretty logic; The field controller handle every field separately.

But talking about performance, loading a single node will require many queryes - or many joins.

I've taken a different approach (even becose my app does not provides any base field): for every field i add a new column on the base table that will store a *raw* value, then a table for every field that need it (multiple fields for example, or reference to other entities) and an *relation* table with just indexes entity_id | field_id (that table actually do other kind of jobs, as keep track of versioningn and kind of relations between entities)

So with a single query i get all the *raw* data from an entity, then the field controller knows (when required) how and where to load the *real* values of that fields.

The column's type in the *data* table (table_entity_data) is the best guess for the field data: for text is text, for decimal is decimal; only for multiple fields (that have theyre value outside that table) is array (and the real data_type is in the _field_foo_value.entity_value_ column)

Assuming that the entity structure wont change often, i tryed to normalize the structure..

Given that other big projects handle this in a very different way I have come to doubt about my implementation, and wondering what kind of problem will happen with my *hibryd* structure:

```
table entity
id

table entity_data
entity_id | field_foo_rav_value | field_bar_raw_value

table relations
entity_id | entity_field_id | field_id_value

table field_foo_value
field_value_id | entity_value

// lets say field_bar is a single text field, there no will be another table:
// entity_data.field_bar_raw_value contains the real value
```

Any suggestion?

p.s: i know this question is kindly generic, feel free to flag for closing if not appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're re-inventing EAV

http://www.google.com/search?q=entity+attribute+value+antipattern

Downsides are that you're throwing away all the type safety and structure that a relational database can provide.

In an ideal world, you probably want one of:

1. Allow the building of a proper table
2. Use a non-relational database

Comment: _Downsides are that you're throwing away all the type safety and structure that a relational database can provide._ mmmh no, im using the datatype correctly, i just didnt talk about that.. let me update my question